# Android Studio sometimes using the deprecated ''fill_parent'

Tags: android, android-studio

I just downloaded Android Studio May 10, 2014 and started using the rich layout editor.

I noticed that when I would drag and drop a `RelativeLayout`, Android Studio would automatically use `fill_parent` for both the `layout_width` and the `layout_height` attributes.

Why does Android Studio not fill in the non-deprecated value, `match_parent` by default?

Comment: Well, AFAIK, Android Studio is still a BETA...

Comment: @Der Golem - Android Studio has not even REACHED beta yet!    On their website the Android tools team says that they'll let us know when they have one ready to be called beta.  All the current releases of Android Studio are considered "preview" quality, which roughly translates to alpha.  See [http://tools.android.com/preview-channel](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been filed as a bug but has not yet been confirmed.  You can see the bug report [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96458).

Answer (score 1):

Because it's in alpha stage of development :)

Comment: MATCH_PARENT has been standard since API level 8!

Comment: Yes but the point is that the IDE has many bugs to work out.  Maybe they ported in the layout generating code from an old ADT plugin from before API 8, who knows.  There is no reason that they use `fill_parent`.

Comment: I misunderstood the answer as meaning the constant MATCH_PARENT is considered alpha.